# Find LUN id for Hitachi stotage on Linux server

Tags: linux, hard-disk, san

I'm able to find existing WWID`EMC LUN` id by using INQ utility but for Hitachi it is not possible. Do you guys have any idea to find the LUN's. For Solaris and AIX I have no issues and the problem is only with Linux end.

Comment: welcome to U&L, do you want to get a LUN number from a wwid ? ( like 360060e80221710005041171000000103 ) , do you want to add new LUN/device without rebooting ?

Answer (score 0):

this is valid for some hitachi, (you mention hitachi in title and EMC in body by the way).

now, if you have LUN id like 360060e80221710005041171000000103

this break down as

- 6**0060e8**0221710005041171000000103 Hitachi
- 60060e8**022**1710005041171000000103  type 0x022 : GSP G200/G400/G600 (add 400000 to serial number)
- 60060e8022171000504**11710**00000103 : serial number in hex (that would give 71440+400000 = 471440 )
- 60060e8022171000504117100000**0103** : LUN number in hex (here 259)